# How can I make find_if function in this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

```
Edge {
    int source, dest, weight;
};

struct Node {
    int vertex, weight;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Edge> edges =
    {
    {0,1,2}, {0,2,3}, {1,3,-1}, {2,3,2}           // (edge1, edge2, weight)
    };

}
```

I want to create a function to see if the weight of the edge is negative or positive. How can I make the function?

Comment: What C++ version are you using?

Comment: Read the docs on `find_if`.  Try something.  Report back what the issue is.

Comment: I use c++ 17 version

Answer (score 5):

> I wanted to create a function that would output false if even one negative weight was negative. For example, if the first one was {0,1,-2} instead of {0,1,2} it's false

Why reinvent the wheel?

If I understand correctly what you want, it's a works for `std::all_of()`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Edge
 { int source, dest, weight; };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<Edge> edges1 { {0,1,2}, {0,2,3}, {1,3,-1}, {2,3,2} },
                     edges2 { {0,1,2}, {0,2,3}, {1,3,+1}, {2,3,2} };

   auto l = [](auto const & elem) { return elem.weight >= 0; };

   auto b1 { std::all_of(edges1.cbegin(), edges1.cend(), l) },
        b2 { std::all_of(edges2.cbegin(), edges2.cend(), l) };

   std::cout << b1 << std::endl; // prints 0
   std::cout << b2 << std::endl; // prints 1
 }
```

More generally speaking, a suggestion: try to use the structures and the algorithms that are available through the standard library.

Comment: Nice use of `std::all_of`.

Comment: @Surt - is available exactly for this sort of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom function and iterate over the vector to check the `weight` property of the particular edge.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct Edge {
    int source, dest, weight;
}Edge;

/*
Function to check if all weights are positive.
Ouput: Returns true (boolean) if all weights are positive and false (boolean) if any one of the weights is negative
*/
bool find_if(std::vector<Edge> edges){
    
    for(size_t i; i < edges.size(); i++){
        if(edges[i].weight < 0){
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Edge> edges =
    {
        {0,1,2}, {0,2,3}, {1,3,-1}, {2,3,2}           // (edge1, edge2, weight)
    };

    std::cout<<(find_if(edges)? "True" : "False")<<std::endl;
}
```